# Issue when trying to install the feedzirra gem in Ruby 1.8.7-p374

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

```
System: Ubuntu 12.0.4
```

I am developing an application in `Ruby-1.8.7-p374` and `rails 2.3.8`

I am trying to install the `feedzirra` gem but I keep on getting the following error:

```
gem install feedzirra --version "= 0.0.23"
ERROR:  Error installing feedzirra:
    nokogiri requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2.
```

I checked my gem list and `nokogiri` is already installed. I tried to install a different version of `nokogiri` but the error persists.

How can I properly install `feedzirra`?

Thanks

Comment: are you using rvm or any other version manager?

Answer (score 0):

Feedzirra is no more exist (last version is 0.8). Authors renamed the project to "Feedjira", so try it: http://feedjira.com/ .
And also install by RVM other versions of Ruby, cause there are many important differences beetwen 1.8 and 1.9+ versions.